# Access remote database

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, remote-access

I'm trying to access a remote database, located on my server, from my local machine.

so what I did is tis:

1. From my server cpanel, i want to remote Mysql, and grant access to my IP adr.
2. From my local machine i tried to connect to the database using a PHP code :

```php
    try {
        $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=the Shared IP Address;dbname=MyDB','MyUsername','Mypassword');
        return $bdd;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "echec connexion with the database";
    }
```

so in :

- the host i tried my **DOMAINE name** and **the shared IP adr**
- for the username and password, i used a user that have access to that database.

and the result was that I can't connect to the database.

so my question is :

are my steps correct !!

and what is the correct methode to this.

Comment: Will only work if the database server allows remote connections and the DB user is allowed to make remote connections. Contact your host

Comment: if your familiar with [redbean](https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php), and your host doesn't support remote connections you could use RPC, shameless plug: https://github.com/plinker-rpc/redbean plop the server part on server, connect to it with the client, run your db calls as if its local

Comment: The IP you have provided could be your `WIFI` IP, get your original external `Your public IP address` IP by putting "what is my ip" in google search and put that IP in the CPANEL

Answer (score 0):

The IP you have provided could be your `WIFI` IP, get your original external `Your public IP address` IP by putting "what is my ip" in google search and put that IP in the CPANEL